# Bootstrap grid not recognize by all my browsers on windows xp

Tags: browser, grid, windows-xp, twitter-bootstrap-3, compatibility

Whatever my grid class: col-2, col-4 and so on are not take in charge in all browsers when I run it on windows xp. The grid become all at 100%. It work perfectly with all browsers ( exept ie8) when i run it with windows 7. I just dont understand. Someone can help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're more likely to get useful answers if you include some distilled sample code in this question so we can try to reproduce the problem. See stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for further advice

Comment: Bootstrap 3 requires the support of media queries, otherwise you will always get the mobile version. Check to see whether those browser versions support media queries.